# Form resizes itself on random

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

### EDIT: I rewrote the question omitting the rambling part.

I'm writing a Win Forms program in Visual Studio 2012. I'm using Windows 8 x64. When i try to run the program on my PC (Debugging or by itself) the form changes size on it's own. The bottom gets lowered by about 50 points i think.

This happens only when i use something other then `Sizable` set as Form Border Style.

It doesn't seem to harm my code but it's annoying and this time it made me think i deleted a control by accident.

It's only doing this on my PC, i don't know if it's the OS or something other. My moms laptop is running Win7 x86 and on that it works properly.

---

Pictures:

Should look like this:

[image]

[image]

But looks like this instead:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

If you need more Info say so!

---

EDIT #1:

Also if anyone happens to know a good book or program that helps learn c# please say so. I tried the program of 3D Buzz and i tried one book called c# in 30 days or something like that and c# for sharp kids, but neither was really that good, 3D Buzz was OK but I didn't always feel like working along with them on the project (XNA extreme) so i kinda lost track at some point...

EDIT #2

@Cody Gray

Thanks, I tried every setting for that (i think `DPI`,`Font`,`Inherit`,`None`) but it didn't change anything

Also I can upload bigger pictures if necessary, i scaled them down on purpose, didn't want to upload pictures that are about 600x600 or so.

EDIT #3

@Hans Passant

I checked, Settings are:

smaller - 100% (default)

Change only the text size:

Title bars :    11

Menus :          9

Message Boxes :  9

Palette Titles : 9

Icons :          9

Tooltips :       9

(neither of them set to bold)

EDIT #4

I checked it on my moms laptop. She's using Windows 7 x86, and she has her Display settings set to Medium, but on her laptop it changes differently, all the forms are as they should and the buttons too, only the RichTextBox is resized not to fit the form properly.

Comment: Can't tell for sure from the tiny pictures, but chances are that your new system has a different font size or DPI setting than your old system did. Check the form's `AutoScaleMode` property.

Comment: Right-click the desktop, Personalize, Display.  The "Change the size of all items" settings matters, some odds you've got Medium selected.  So your form got resized as well.  You'll need to fix the layout oopses that causes.